# Is the secret seed number also the private number?

Tags: wallet-recovery, coinbase.com, seed

I purchased a bitcoin in 2014 from Coinbase. I received a long alphanumeric number. No private code or seed phrase. I received a 16-digit secret seed at a later date. Is the secret seed I received a replacement for the seed phrase or private number that I can use to access my bitcoins on Coinbase?

Comment: The best resource to find this out would probably be Coinbase's user manual, but perhaps someone here is familiar enough with the service's offering to be able to tell you.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with looking at the alfanumeric number.
Is it in hexadecimal? If yes , is it 32 bytes long --> random number
Is it a code that begins with a 5 or L or K --> Private key

Never share any of these.
But you can calculate the Public key and the Bitcoin address from those.